How to mock StreamingRespone?
Imagine there is a FastAPI application with files structure:
src:
- app.py
- responses.py
- test_download.py

I return a custom StreamingRespone:
# responses.py

from fastapi.responses import StreamingRespone


class CustomStreamingRespone(StreamingRespone):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self._url = url

I return CustomStreamingRespone in a view:
# app.py

from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/act/download/")
async def download_act(...):
    # search for url...
    return CustomStreamingRespone(url=url)


@app.get("/report/download/")
async def download_report(...):
    # search for url...
    return CustomStreamingRespone(url=url)


# there might be multiple views that return CustomStreamingRespone

I'm trying to mock CustomStreamingRespone (with pytest) like this:
# test_download.py

async def test_act_downloaded(client: httpx.AsyncClient, mocker: MockerFixture):
    # preparing data for test might be identical in part of preparing content inside CustomStreamingRespone
    mock = mocker.patch("responses.CustomStreamingRespone")
    resp = await client.get("/act/download")
    mock.assert_called()  # fails with error AssertionError: Expected 'CustomStreamingRespone' to have been called. 
    assert resp == mock.return_value


async def test_report_downloaded(client: httpx.AsyncClient, mocker: MockerFixture):
    ...

But this does not work.
I just need to test that CustomStreamingRespone was used (the fact of use).
How could I mock CustomStreamingRespone when testing views?
P.S. I've just realized that I should mock CustomStreamingRespone.__call__ method?

It is important that you provide full path of the files you're importing your modules from. You don't necessarily need the mocker module either. Also, you need to import your app and initialise a test_client instance. Quite a few things you're missing out on. If you can mention the file paths and everything in your question, I can quickly work it out for you

@climate-coder, I've added more details, provided project structure

You need to first import the CustomStreamingResponse into your app.py. This should be the file:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from responses import CustomStreamingRespone

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/act/download/")
async def download_act(...):
    # search for url...
    return CustomStreamingRespone(url=url)

Additionally, you need to adjust the entry points for your application. I'm not sure what your entry points are so the way I'm importing your relevant class may or may not work for you.
You then need to mock the app itself. And now to the tricky bit, to mock a function or a class, you need to mock the instance you import into the file itself from within the file. So pay attention to the import path for the mock in the code below(again adjust as per your entry points).
from app import app
from httpx import AsyncClient
import pytest

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@mock.patch("app.CustomStreamingRespone")
async def test_download_act(mock_custom_streaming_response):
    url = "abc"
    mock_custom_streaming_response_instance = (
        mock_custom_streaming_response.return_value
    )
    mock_custom_streaming_response_instance.return_value = "abc"

    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        response = await ac.get("/act/download/")

    assert response == mock_custom_streaming_response_instance.return_value
    mock_custom_streaming_response.assert_called_once()

Couple of things for you to notice here. Since your endpoints are asynchronous, you need to the pytest asyncio decorator.
